# Highcharts: display peak values

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I would like to display difference between 2 points on my Highcharts graph. Only when it's a major "peak" difference.

Here's a "static" example :

[image]

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'areaspline'
        },
        series: [{
            data:   [560,500,476,453,356,{
                        y: 590,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            formatter: function () {return '+243';}
                        } 
                    },497,478,465,465,465,410,398]
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vr1a61wy/

How can I compare all point values with the previous ?

For example, something like that (not "real code)

```
if(prevValue > 200) {
  displayDataLabel();
}
function displayDataLabel() {
   peak = this.datalabel - prev.datalabel;
   return peak;
}
```

The goal is to have a clean json file only with values and peaks calculated by javascript.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter` to do this comparison. To do the comparison you will utilize `this.x`, `this.y` and `this.series` to look up the previous point.

An example `formatter` function would be ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4a8L9qe/1/)):

```
formatter: function() {
    if(this.x > 0 && this.y - this.series.data[this.x-1].y >= PEAKDIFF) {
        return "+" + (this.y - this.series.data[this.x-1].y);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Where `PEAKDIFF` is the value you want the difference to be before showing the label. If you want large negative drops to show as well you'd do the same with `Math.abs`.

Comment: Thanks Ondkloss, I'll try that and post the results

Comment: This answer assumes the previous `x` value is `x-1`, which isn't necessarily the case.  It's safer to look up the index, like `this.series.data.indexOf( this.point ) - 1`.  For very large series continuously looking up points will be a performance killer, so it's probably best to cache the index, maybe in the point object itself.